# The definite article in: être l'un(e) de quelque chose

Tags: articles, articles-definis, absence-d-article

> *La journée d'aujourd'hui va être— sera
>
> **l'** un des grands jours de ma vie.*

> *La franchise est **l'** une de mes qualités*

Why do we add a definite article in French before un(e)? Why do we say: it's *the* one of sth?

Sentences in more clear contexts.

> *Nous sommes aujourd'hui le 1er septembre 1979. Nous sommes un lundi, le premier jour de la semaine; c'est aussi le premier jour du mois! Ce n'est pas le premier jour de l'année; mais, tant pis! **La journée d'aujourd'hui va être— sera l'un des grands jours de ma vie**. Ma résolution est prise; le premier pas est fait : je commence à écrire mon journal.*

> *La sacrifice de maman n'a pas été récompensé. L'oncle Noël est mort, et nous n'avons pas hérité de sa fortune. Franchement, c'est dommage. Oui, j'ai le courage de l'avouer: **la franchise est l'une de mes qualités**.*

Comment: Here's what I think is a [complete answer](https://www.antidote.info/fr/blogue/enquetes/un-des-ou-lun-des) to your question, ***l'***  is optional in the sentences you give, sometimes having it is better, very rarely compulsory (a few phrases).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing makes the definite article compulsory in any of the sentences you give. Its use in this case belong to a sustained language register.

Here's what *Le bon usage* (10<sup>e</sup> edition,§ 594) says:

> Le pronom un construit avec *un* complément partitif (...) peut être précédé de l'article élidé, mais le plus souvent il s'emploie sans cet article (sauf *de deux choses l'une*, *de deux jours l'un*, où l'article est indispensable)<sup>1</sup>.

[This page](https://www.antidote.info/fr/blogue/enquetes/un-des-ou-lun-des) on *Antidote* specifies that using the elided determiner ***l'*** in this case belongs to a sustained language register.
It is preferable to use it to prevent a hiatus after a word ended with a vowel sound (*et, ou, où, qui quoi, si*) and in front of plural personal pronouns *nous, vous, eux* and *elles*.
It is preferable not to use it when it would cause an alliteration.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> When used with a partitive complement *un* can be preceded by the elided article (l'), but most often it is used without the article (except *de deux choses l'une*, *de deux jours l'un* where the article is compulsory). (My translation)</sup>